# For-loop error in rstudio says 'undefined columns'

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop, undefined

I've been playing around with some for-loops and functions, but I can't quite get them to work. I've generated four columns of random numbers, with 300 rows each and collected them into a single dataframe.

```
numbers <- runif(300, min = 0, max = 250)

numbers <- as.data.frame(numbers)

numbers$numbers2 <- runif(300, min = 0, max = 300)

numbers$numbers3 <- runif(300, min = 0, max = 350)

numbers$numbers4 <- runif(300, min = 0, max = 400)

numbers <- as.data.frame(numbers)
```

I then created a function to compute the z-scores for the numbers in each column:

```
newfunction <- function(x){    
x_stand <- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
return(x_stand)    
}
```

I want to implement the function in a for-loop and calculate the z-scores for all the four columns, but I get an error message when I try to run the following code:

```
for (i in numbers[,1:4]) {    
  z_scores[i] <- newfunction(numbers[,i])    
}
```

The error message reads: [.data.frame`(numbers, , i) : undefined columns selected

I would just like to the for-loop to calculate the z-scores for each variable/column in the "numbers" dataframe and plug these calculations into a dataframe called z_scores, such that the final z_scores dataframe contains four new columns that each contain the z-scores corresponding the with ith column in the "numbers" dataframe.

Can anyone tell me what I need to fix to make my for-loop work properly?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `(i in 1:4)`  but you're going to run into another issue because you didn't create a `z_scores` data frame ahead of time. You could just do `z_scores <- numbers` before the loop to quickly remedy this.

Comment: Why not just use `numbers.z <- scale(numbers)`?

Comment: I am just playing around with functions and for-loops to teach myself :) I tried creating a z_scores dataframe assigned to numbers and changed the for-loop to for (i in 1:4) ... 

In total, it looks like the following now: z_scores <- as.data.frame(numbers) 
for (i in 1:4) {

z_scores[i] <- myfunction(numbers[i]) 

}

I get the following error message though: "list object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your loop condition `for (i in numbers[,1:4])`. On each iteration of your loop this sets `i` to the vector of the corresponding column, **not** to the *column name*, which seems to have been your intention.

You can get your desired performance with either:

```
for (i in colnames(numbers[,1:4])) {    
  z_scores[i] <- newfunction(numbers[,i])    
}
```

or

```
for (i in numbers[,1:4]) {    
  z_scores[i] <- newfunction(i)   # Since i is the vector of values, there is no need to subset the dataframe numbers
}
```